# template method pattern - naming conventions

Tags: java, naming-conventions, template-method-pattern

I have this abstract class named as **RenderableEntity** .

I have a public method `render()` that has some logic wrapped around abstract protected `render()` method. How should I name this abstract `render()` method. Is there some kind of convention eg. `doRender()`, `makeRender()` for protected method `render()`?

```
public abstract class RenderableEntity extends Entity {

    private boolean visible;

    public void render(){
        if(visible){
            render();
        }
    }
    protected abstract void render();
}
```

***Edit**: I know this snippet does not compile. I was just wondering how to name this abstract method since I can't have methods with same name and same parameters.*

Comment: What about giving the abstract method a different name and leaving the other method with just render? For example name the abstract method as aRender.

Comment: Your code in current form will not compile as there are two methods with same name..

Comment: Think it is better to discuss with your colleagues. IMHO I would use renderImpl or renderInternal name. Because I want to explain method contain main logic for render.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First: Only consider special naming for methods like these if they are for *exclusive use* by the template method. In addition, you should comment these methods stating that they are used by the template method and any modifications should be made with that usage in mind.

The methods that make up replaceable steps in a template method are often called "hook" methods. You'll sometimes see them named with "Hook" at the end.

In your example, you may want to call it `renderHook()`, though if you can get more specific on the task that it is performing within the template method `render()` that would be more descriptive.

I have seen `doXXX()` used, though it's primarily when there is a one-to-one template-to-hook relationship.

A possible suggestion. For a template method `stuff()`:

- If `stuff()` is primarily simple control logic around a single hook, name the hook `doStuff()` (This seems to be the case in your example above)
- If `stuff()` orchestrates several hooks, name them independently with `Hook` suffixes, and do not name *any* of them the same as the template (in this case, there should be no `stuffHook()` method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no convention about it. But I would prefer to see more meaningfull name. E.g. `forceRender`, `renderNow`, `renderImmideately` or something similar which tells the fact it renders somehow differently than just `render`.

Answer (score 0):

**Template Method Pattern** doesn't have any such guideline on naming convention. But do give appropriate name so that it clearly explains **intent** of the method and **maintenance** of same is easier in future.